# How can I use go workspace to load dependencies locally?

Tags: go

I have a go workspace project which includes a few go modules. A module depends another module in the same workspace. I'd like to make the dependency to be resolved locally without downloading from internet.

I have two modules, `hello` and `example`. `hello` depends on `example`. The structure is:

```
example
  - go.mod
  - hello
     - go.mod
hello
  - go.mod
go.work
```

The `go.work` is:

```
go 1.19

use (
    ./example/hello
    ./hello
)
```

The module `hello` needs to use a function declared from `example -> hello` module. The `go.mod` under `example/hello` is:

```
module github.com/example/hello

go 1.19
```

When I run `go get github.com/example/hello` under `hello` directory, I got error:

```
go: module github.com/example/hello: git ls-remote -q origin in /Users/joey/go/pkg/mod/cache/vcs/85c69767672480b072ae4eaec76fbf39ef710d025b14e923dd131ac218c9034c: exit status 128:
    fatal: could not read Username for 'https://github.com': terminal prompts disabled
Confirm the import path was entered correctly.
If this is a private repository, see https://golang.org/doc/faq#git_https for additional information.
```

It seems `go` still wants to download the dependency from `github.com` rather than looking at local worksapce. Is there a way to force `go` to look at local directory first?

The full code is: https://github.com/zhaoyi0113/go-workspace

Comment: 1. Follow https://go.dev/doc/tutorial/workspaces. 2. You have a module in example and one in example/hello, that's one too much as you said "I have two modules". You seem to mix up the concept of "module" and "package". 3. Too many hello directories. When you say "When I run [...] under hello directory" it's unclear which of the two. Use distinct names. 4. You should show the names of the modules. Again: Use distinct names.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The module name in the go.mod file is tied to the project structure. Otherwise, randomly naming it might cause conflicts with other libraries, making it unclear which one to pull when building dependencies.

In other words, the directory structure must match for you to fetch code from GitHub. So, change the module name in the go.mod file under the "example" directory to:

```
module github.com/zhaoyi0113/go-workspace/example
```

And for the "hello" directory:

```
module github.com/zhaoyi0113/go-workspace/hello
```

If the "hello" directory needs to depend on the "example" module, import it as follows:

```
require (
    github.com/zhaoyi0113/go-workspace/example xxxx
)
```

Here, "xxxx" can be the version number if you have created a release. If not, you can use the Git commit hash from the code you pushed to GitHub. You can find the Git hash on the GitHub project page for "example." In the "hello" directory, execute the following command:

```
go get github.com/zhaoyi0113/go-workspace/example@{git version prefix, which can be found on the GitHub project page}
```

However, this approach only allows you to fetch the code that has been pushed to GitHub. If you want to quickly debug and develop locally, you can add a "replace" directive in the go.mod file:

```
replace github.com/zhaoyi0113/go-workspace/example => {local directory of your example}
```

---

update

It is recommended to organize the project structure using the package approach, where modules should be more independent and typically located in different repositories.

```
.
├── example
│    ├── reverse
│    └── utils.go
├── hello
│    └── hello.go
├── go.mod
├── go.sum
└── main.go
```

Comment: If I don't want to release a tag in the repo and use `replace`, is there any reason I still need to use go workspace?

Comment: cd hello  and go get github.com/zhaoyi0113/go-workspace/example@xxxx

Comment: xxxx = project - git version prefix

Comment: Furthermore, would it be better to use a subpackage approach here instead of employing two separate modules? Subpackages provide a more independent concept of modules, especially when structures in a project are interrelated and need to call each other. Using packages is a more suitable choice in such cases, and you can refer to the updated section in the above answer for how to organize the project structure when using packages

Comment: I am doing a monorepo structure which means I can't put everything under one folder. It is annoying that I have to manually change go.mod to use `replace` when working locally. Then change it back when creating a PR. I was hopping go workspace can do that local dependency resolvers.

Comment: the replace directive in Go modules supports relative paths. You can use relative paths to specify the local path of the module you want to replace, making it easier to test or debug during development.

Comment: If I use `replace directive`, then there is no reason to use `go workspace`?